# HTML label for ACE editor?

Tags: html, ace-editor, label-for

I have a `<div>` based ACE editor.

```
<label for="editorId">Content</label><div id="editorId></div>
```

Is it possible to make `<label>` with `for` attribute work without adding onclick event?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to assign id to the hidden textarea used by ace

```
editor.container.id = ""; // remove id from container div
editor.textInput.getElement().id = "editorId"; // assign id to the textarea
```